# How to create a thumbnail image of webpages in objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am rookie to iOS. In my project i need to add thumbnail image of web pages in image view.I created a NSObject class for that. I initiated web view in that class but it won't call the UIWebView Delegates.I posted the code here. If any one have solution or the library file for thumbnail processing that might be useful.Thank you.

```
@interface ThumbNail()<UIWebViewDelegate>
{
    UIImageView *thumbNailImageView;
    UIWebView *mockUpWebView;
    UIImage *viewImage;
}
@end

@implementation ThumbNail

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
   thumbNailImageView.image = [self captureScreen:webView];
}

-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"Errorrr.............");
}

-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest     *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
   NSLog(@"Got it");
   return YES;
}

-(UIImage*)captureScreen:(UIWebView*) viewToCapture{
    CGSize overallSize = CGSizeMake(mockUpWebView.frame.size.width, mockUpWebView.frame.size.width);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(viewToCapture.scrollView.contentSize);
    viewToCapture.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, overallSize.width, overallSize.height);
    while (viewToCapture.loading) {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
    } 
    [viewToCapture.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return viewImage;
}

-(void)getThumbNailForImageView:(UIImageView *)imageView{
    thumbNailImageView = imageView;
    NSString *urlAddress = @"https://in.yahoo.com/?p=us";

    //Create a URL object.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

    //URL Requst Object
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //Load the request in the UIWebView.
    CGRect bounds              = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    mockUpWebView              = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:bounds];
    NSLog(@"bounds = %@",NSStringFromCGRect(bounds));
    mockUpWebView.delegate     = self;
    [mockUpWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
@end
```

I am trying to get thumbnail image by calling getThumbNailForImageView.